# Dynamically create onclick event anchor element - Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, onclick, href

How do I dynamically create a onclick function in a hyperlink in JavaScript?

This is a code snippet - a while loop that creates several hyperlinks within the same page. I tried to just add the onclick event to the a-element, that is:

```
a.onclick=myfunction()
```

However, when the page is loaded with a list of these links, the function is automatically called for every link.

This is how my code looks like. I guess I should use an **id** for every link?

```
  var a = document.createElement('a');
  var linkText = document.createTextNode(child.innerHTML);
  a.appendChild(linkText);
  a.title = child.innerHTML;
  a.href = "#stockContent" + i;
  a.id = "link_id" + i;

  ...
```

"i" is the iterator variable.

Comment: I would definitely get in the habit of putting id's on the things you wish to manipulate. and just do something like "a.addEventListener('onclick', function(event){ do stuff here})". That would work. It wouldn't instantly execute - it would only execute "onclick" by having an event listener :). It's also possible to create custom event methods/listeners if required.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
a.onclick=myfunction()
```

Will set the return value of `myfunction` as onclick. What you want is the following:

```
a.onclick=myfunction
```

Answer (score 2):

You can specify the onclick function in two ways:

1) with a named function:

```
function myFunction(){
  alert('hello');
}

a.onclick = myFunction;
```

2) with an anonymous function:

```
a.onclick = function(){ 
  alert('hello'); 
};
```